# Updating a variable to the value of a string only returns the first character of the string

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to hard code the major ticks for a plot by creating an array which I will then attach to the x-axis of the graph. However, I can't get the array to come out correctly. I created an empty list `xticks` which I want to update every 5th value the correct value from `major_ticks` but the updated values are only the first characters of the values in `major_ticks`

```
{
    length_x = 21
    import numpy as np

    xticks=np.full(length_x,'',dtype=str) 
    #print(xticks) returns ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']

    major_ticks=np.linspace(-10,10,5,dtype=int) 
    #print(major_ticks) returns [-10  -5   0   5  10]

    i=0
    for j in range(len(xticks)):
        if j%5==0:
            xticks[j]=str(major_ticks[i])
            i+=1

    print(xticks) #returns ['-' '' '' '' '' '-' '' '' '' '' '0' '' '' '' '' '5' '' '' '' '' '1']

}
```

please help me understand why this is happening, I've been banging my head against the wall for 3 hours now.

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: Make the string dtype is long enough

Comment: Please explain the meaning of your sentence: [I can't get the array to come out correctly. I created an empty list "xticks" which I want to update every 5th value the correct value from "major_ticks"]  I'd like to try to help, but I don't understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `np.full` doesn't generate an array of strings in the first place but an array of chars:

```
np.full(length_x,'',dtype=str).dtype
dtype('<U1')
```

Typically I wouldn't recommend to use `numpy` for string operations. Replacing `xticks=np.full(length_x,'',dtype=str)` with `xticks = [''] * length_x` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's something funky going on with your `np.full` declaration. Switching to using python lists will make it easier:

```py
major_ticks=np.linspace(-10,10,5,dtype=int)
xticks = []

i=0
for j in range(length_x):
    if j%5==0:
        tick = str(major_ticks[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        tick = ''
    xticks.append(tick)

print(xticks)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [129]: major_ticks=np.linspace(-10,10,5,dtype=int)                                                        
In [130]: major_ticks.shape                                                                                  
Out[130]: (5,)
In [133]: major_ticks                                                                                        
Out[133]: array([-10,  -5,   0,   5,  10])
In [134]: major_ticks.astype(str)                                                                            
Out[134]: array(['-10', '-5', '0', '5', '10'], dtype='<U21')
```

Making strings from `major_ticks`.  21 is bigger than needed, but who's counting?

```
In [135]: xticks=np.full(21,'',dtype='U21')                                                                  
In [136]: xticks                                                                                             
Out[136]: 
array(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', ''], dtype='<U21')

In [138]: i=0 
     ...: for j in range(len(xticks)): 
     ...:     if j%5==0: 
     ...:         xticks[j] = str(major_ticks[i]) 
     ...:         i+=1 
     ...:          
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [139]: xticks                                                                                             
Out[139]: 
array(['-10', '', '', '', '', '-5', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '',
       '5', '', '', '', '', '10'], dtype='<U21')
```

But we can fill the string array directly:

```
In [140]: xticks=np.full(21,'',dtype='U21')                                                                  
In [141]: xticks[0::5] = major_ticks                                                                         
In [142]: xticks                                                                                             
Out[142]: 
array(['-10', '', '', '', '', '-5', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '',
       '5', '', '', '', '', '10'], dtype='<U21')
```

The integers are converted to the string dtype as they are added to `xticks`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like dtype=str defaults to length limit of 1. Set dtype='U10' or 'S10' instead or something.